# O que são propriedades dinâmicas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, propriedade

Estou estudando ASP.NET e vi o seguinte trecho de código:

```
ViewBag.QtdNovosComunicados =  
(from
   c in comunicados
 where
   c.DataCadastro > UsuarioLogado.dtUltimoAcesso
 select
c).Count();
```

Entendi que estou criando uma nova propriedade na classe `ViewBag`.

Mas como ele definirá essa propriedade dinâmica? O .NET faz isso em tempo de execução? Podem ocorrer problemas de tipo quando eu for acessar essa propriedade posteriormente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewBag` é um objeto, não uma classe. Ele é uma propriedade da `View` que é utilizada para montar a página.

Os valores são passados para a View em tempo de execução, mas isso não quer dizer que sejam fracamente tipados. Se você tentar utilizar esses valores de forma que os tipos não permitem, você vai ter exceções. Por exemplo, o resultado de uma chamada a `Count()` como no exemplo na pergunta é inteiro - se você tentar chamar um método que inteiro não possui, como `Dispose()`, você obtém um erro.

Só mais uma coisa: `ViewBag` é uma coisa muito fácil de se utilizar para cometer abusos, e por isso seu uso é considerado na melhor das hipóteses um *code smell* (eufemismo para gambiarra pequena), e na pior das hipóteses um anti-padrão. A forma tradicional de se passar dados para a `View` é preencher esses dados no `Model`, não no `ViewBag`.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta bem esclarecedora. No caso onde precisamos acessar dados de mais de um modelo na view, como em relatórios, é correto utilizar o objeto viewBag ou seria o caso de um code smell como citado?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero você pode criar um modelo específico para a View de relatório, que tem os dados preenchidos a partir de outros objetos (que podem ser inclusive outros modelos). Sugiro dar uma olhada em composição em orientação a objetos.

Comment: Beleza, vou pesquisar aqui, mais uma vez obrigado :)